# How can I create a link between mnt/sdcard and sdcard on android x86 4.3?

Tags: virtualbox, android-sdcard, android-x86

I am trying to give the virtual machine android x86 ultimately have a fake sdcard. It is getting tricky for me and I am running through the multiple scenarios. The problem is stemming from applications that point towards mnt/sdcard for references, but the directory is empty because it is not automatically synching with the sdcard folder.

On the website they say to make 2 partitions, one for the os and the other for the sdcard. I am not making any progress with that method.

My next choice is to copy all files from the sdcard folder into the mnt/sdcard folder. This works unfortunately I must execute a chmod command on mnt/sdcard under su every time the phone starts up. I am trying to make this a one time operation instead.

My last resort is to execute a script that does the remedial commands on start up, copying the contents of the sdcard folder to mnt/sdcard. Still this does not account for anything added to the sdcard folder afterwards. The manual creation of a symlink between the two folders is the best option for longevity.

That doesn't include the partition example. For anyone familiar with android x86 on VM's The process is as follows:

1. Create two partitions
   a. Bootable primary sda1 linux/ntfs
   b. primary sda2 fat36
2. Install android on sda1
3. reboot device/vm
4. Set partition 2 in kernel / GRUB, 2 options
   a. scroll to vesa and press tab and enter
   b. Press A and enter "DATA=/dev/sda1 SDCARD=/dev/sda2"
5. after setup complete navigate to settings and click storage
   a. Mount and format sdcard shazam the sdcard works and is mounted